# How to get ecm.widget.viewer.ContentViewer items

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I have a page where first half (vertical) of the page has a gridx and second half of the page has a contentViewer. When a user clicks on an item from the grid, I'm loading the respective image and is working fine. When the user clicks on the second item from grid, the viewer is loading the second image but the issue is it is retaining the first image as well (images are opened as a tab). So I need to remove the first image when loading the second image. Is there a way to get items from ContentViewer so that I can close the previous one before loading the new one?

Answer (score 0):

The getViewersStatus() method of ContentViewer will return to you a structure that includes all the currently open items. You can then iterate through this and call closeItem() on each one.

But if you are using Navigator 2.0.3.3 or later, what you probably want to do is call closeAllViewers() on the ContentViewer widget to close all open items without prompt to save changes.

Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEUEX_2.0.3/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/doc/JavaScriptdoc/symbols/ecm.widget.viewer.ContentViewer.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I looked into the method getViewersStatus(includePrinting) and it says 
"Returns a data structure containing information about all open viewers that have unsaved changes, and/or are in the process of printing."  When I used this method, I got no items. Also, I tried to use closeAllViewers() but it's strange that I don't see that method. Even I looked into ecm.widget.viewer.ContentViewer and can't find the method. It could be something wrong with the version of my ICN (Version: 2.0.3 Build: icn203.555). Finally, I got it working and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I did to achieve this.

```
if(this.imgViewer.mainTabContainer.getChildren().length>0){
                array.forEach(this.imgViewer.mainTabContainer.getChildren(),function(child){
                    this.imgViewer.mainTabContainer.removeChild(child);
                });
            }
```